# TLS on SRV Records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

The `SRV` records comply with this format: `_service._proto.domain (and some other values here...)`.

I want to know if anyone has ever used in `_proto` - `tls`. TLS is not a transport protocol, so, is it possible to use it there? I know that in `_service` you can add security, but is it possible on the transport protocol as well?

Comment: Are you trying to do TLS on nonstandard ports?

Comment: yes, if I remember correct they are nonstandard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SRV record is defined in [RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) and according to that you may locally choose whatever works for you:

> **Proto**
> The symbolic name of the desired protocol, with an underscore
> (_) prepended to prevent collisions with DNS labels that occur
> in nature.  _TCP and _UDP are at present the most useful values
> for this field, though **any name defined** by Assigned Numbers or
> **locally** *may be used* (as for Service).  The Proto is case
> insensitive.